# How slider contents move to next slide auto on the basis of item-content when its complete a row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I want that the slider content that I will write should be **auto width and height** and when one row completed the other **items auto move to the next slider** carousel.
I am using bootstrap 4 and I have Item-Slider (slider type) that is displaying on site. The code is below of one slider other sliders code are same too.
[This is an auto height and width of content and I want fourth item content auto move to the next slide carousel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOXUZ.png)

```
 <div class="carousel-inner">
<div class="carousel-item active">

   <div class="bannerpic">

  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h1>1 of 1</h1>
      <div class="card-text">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam ornare pharetra elit vitae mollis. Mauris consectetur semper diam ac pretium.

        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam ornare pharetra elit vitae mollis. Mauris consectetur semper diam ac pretium.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h1>1 of 2</h1>
      <div class="card-text">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam ornare pharetra elit vitae mollis. Mauris consectetur semper diam ac pretium.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h1>1 of 3</h1>
      <div class="card-text">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam ornare pharetra elit vitae mollis. Mauris consectetur semper diam ac pretium.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

         <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h1>1 of 1</h1>
      <div class="card-text">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam ornare pharetra elit vitae mollis. Mauris consectetur semper diam ac pretium.

        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam ornare pharetra elit vitae mollis. Mauris consectetur semper diam ac pretium.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Didn't get your point ' items auto move to the next slider  '. Please explain a bit .

Comment: I mean to say 4 col are shown in image I want they show three in image and fourth auto go to the next slide without adding to the next slide. Want an automatic slider that work on the basis of width if width of one slider complete other items auto move to the next slide without making another section on next slide.

Comment: Could you see this link https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/, reffers what you want. Go to this website and search for ' Variable Width '.